# With Spring, I want to automatically generating a table for only one entity in the database inside spring boot (using spring data jpa)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an spring application connected to a mysql database. Inside my schema there are already a bunch of tables with values in them that have already been successfully connected in the spring application with the correct set of entities for them. I would like to add one entity to them.

[api_key_table entity class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5ULI.png)

I have recently added a new entity to my application called "api_key_table" and I was hoping spring would automatically generate a table for it since it doesn't exist but that did not happen. I have been looking online for a way to this and there are ways to generate tables for all of the entities but I could not find anything to help me add only one new table automatically if it doesn't exist.

I ended up creating a sql script that I intended to execute but I didn't find a way to retrieve the same connection spring used to execute my script.

[Sql script to create new table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s1Q3.png)

I updated my application.properties files to automatically create but it ended up overwriting my scheme tables and all the data in it was removed. I only wanted to create one table if it doesn't already exist.

[Application.properties file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yEMt.png)

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: We use `flyway` to execute any DDL, and flyway uses spring datasource connection during application application startup. If possible you can try that.

Comment: Please don't post code images or errors if possible, copy your code or code error into answer with block code format. Please take the tour and read How to Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your question and found one fix which you can do.

you have configured below property like this:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Instead of "create" just give configuration like:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

or

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-only
```

then it will work as per your requirement.